# .htaccess redirect with parameters and multiple directory levels

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect from this URL:

www.devsite.com/level1/page1.html?brand=6

to:

www.productionsite.com/level1/page1.html?brand=6

I've come across various redirect w/ parameters answers here on stack, but none that specifically address how to rewrite part of .htaccess to redirect to a totally different domain. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a redirect from devsite to productionsite. Second line appends after the devsite domain to the new location.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.devsite.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.productionsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the htaccess file in the **document root** of your **`www.devsite.com`** domain. Add it above any other rules that may already be in that file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?devsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^level1/page1\.html$ http://www.productionsite.com/level1/page1.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't seem to get this to work. We already have the following in the .htaccess file: 

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Could that be interfering?

Comment: @TheNovice No, that rule won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \?brand=6
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.devsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^level1/page1\.html$ http%2://www.productionsite.com/$0 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't seem to get this to work. We already have the following in the .htaccess file: 

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Could that be interfering?

Comment: @TheNovice - You should always test each rule separately first